# Android onPictureTaken not being called every time

Tags: android, image, callback, camera

I am trying to take a picture after five minutes. The connection to the camera works fine. When I call takePicture the camera makes a noise (seems to take a photo).

Unfortunately the method onPictureTaken is not always executed. Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not work.

My PictureCallback:

```
 Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback()
             {
                public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera)
                {
```

The situation is always the same (screen on, running in background).

Comment: Put some logging code in your onPause, and onStop functions and repeat the test.  The Android Activity manager may be pausing your app or the camera may be disabled in certain states.  Write code which monitors the ready state of the camera.

Comment: When I press the home button the method onStop is called. This is normal. But it works sometimes although the onStop method is called. The code for the camera is in a broadcast receiver started by the main activity.

Comment: Might it be a timing problem? I am calling two callbacks. The second one 30 seconds after the first one. There are only problems with the second callback.